# Why "position" argument in getItemId of my descendant of BaseAdapter is always 0?

Tags: android, baseadapter

My ListView looks fine but position in my

```
public long getItemId(int position)
```

is always 0. It's being called a lot of times (i guess once per item).
Callstack:

```
MyAdapter.getItemId(int) line: 156  
OverScrollListView(AdapterView).rememberSyncState() line: 1169  
AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver(AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver).onChanged() line: 798    
AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged() line: 6773   
DataSetObservable.notifyChanged() line: 35  
MyAdapter(BaseAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged() line: 50
```

Android 4.1 or 2.3.3 - it doesn't mean.

Thanks in advance!

**I'm sorry, false alarm. getItemId is being called for about 10 times with position == 0 and after gets normal position**

Comment: You should probably post your Adapter code...

Comment: I'm sorry, false alarm. getItemId is being called for about 10 times with position == 0 and after gets normal position.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. But since this question is a "false alarm" you should consider removing it (as it is unlikely to be useful anyone else.)